# How to split python3 List?

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list:

```py
[('5.333333333333333', 'n04'), ('5.0', 'n01'), ('3.9936507936507932', 'n03'), ('2.4206349206349205', 'n05'), ('1.9629629629629628', 'n02')]
```

and I like to have the list like this:

```py
[n04, n01, n03, n02, n04]
```

how to do it? I have spend too many houres on this problem.
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x,y=zip(*[('5.333333333333333', 'n04'), ('5.0', 'n01'), ('3.9936507936507932', 'n03'), ('2.4206349206349205', 'n05'), ('1.9629629629629628', 'n02')])
y=list(y)
print(y)
```

Outputs:

```py
['n04', 'n01', 'n03', 'n05', 'n02']
```

Comment: y here is a tuple not a list so may have issues if the OP then wanted to later modify this.

Comment: Thank you it work,s fine, Thank you Grzegorz Skibinski.

Comment: No worries - happy to help :) - please mark it as an answer, if it addresses your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprension to iterate over the list and pick out the values you are interested in and put them in a new list

```py
my_list = [('5.333333333333333', 'n04'), ('5.0', 'n01'), ('3.9936507936507932', 'n03'), ('2.4206349206349205', 'n05'), ('1.9629629629629628', 'n02')]
my_new = [item[1] for item in my_list]
print(my_new)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['n04', 'n01', 'n03', 'n05', 'n02']
```